# Cannot play video when page visibility changes in iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, html5-video, mobile-safari

I now have videos(muted) in my web app. These videos are inside a `react-slick`, and I control the playback when switching slides. Everything works perfectly when the page visibility stays the same.

When tabs switch, the browser would pause the video. As I return to the tab, the video resumes in Chrome, while it freezes in iOS Safari. I want it resumes in iOS Safari as well.

I've tried the document `visibilitychange` event.
But the video is still paused after I try to play it.

```js
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => {
  const video = this.videoDOMs[this.currentIndex];
  if (document.visibilityState === 'visible' && appUtils.isIOs()) {
    video.play(); // afterwards, video.paused is false but the video still freezes
  }
});
```

Lastly, my workaround is using video `onpause` event.

```
video.onpause = () => {
  if (!video.ended && document.visibilityState === 'visible' && appUtils.isIOs()) {
    video.play(); // video can play
  }
}
```

The workaround works but I still wonder why the visibility change event fails to resume the video.
Any better solutions are pleased to hear.

Comment: I notice that putting the video.play() in a brief setTimeout makes it work.

Comment: Wow, how do you make it?
Can you provide your code snippet~